# How do I manage/close connections if I can't change max_user_connections variable?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I am using shared hosting that has "max user connections" set to 30. I've contacted them and they said they could not change this value. By surfing through my website I get an exception thrown that says:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1203 User id12578877_odonto already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections
```

Most of the actions in my web are just repositories (that have been generated with make:crud command) filtering some data. Upon changing between these pages rapidly for like 30s I get this error.

Is there any way I could reduce the number of connections or just basically anything I could do that would help?

Here is an example of how some of the actions in my controller look:

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="pacientai_index", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(PacientaiRepository $pacientaiRepository): Response
    {
        if($this->getUser()==null){
            return $this->redirectToRoute('main');
        }
        if($this->getUser()->getRole()=="NEW"){
            return $this->redirectToRoute('main');
        }
        if($this->getUser()->getMiestas()=="London"){
            return $this->redirectToRoute('main');
        }
        return $this->render('pacientai/index.html.twig', [
            'pacientais' => $pacientaiRepository->findByStatus("NEW"),
            'sutarti' => $pacientaiRepository->findByStatus("SUTARTAS"),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/mine", name="pacientai_index_mine", methods={"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function myPatients(PacientaiRepository $pacientaiRepository, UserRepository $userRepository): Response
    {
        if($this->getUser()==null){
            return $this->redirectToRoute('main');
        }
        if($this->getUser()->getRole()=="NEW"){
            return $this->redirectToRoute('main');
        }
        if($this->getUser()->getMiestas()=="London"){
            return $this->redirectToRoute('main');
        }
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(User::class)
            ->find($this->getUser()->getId());
        $entity->setYraNauju(0);
        $entityManager->persist($entity);
        $entityManager->flush();
        return $this->render('pacientai/myPatients.html.twig');
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong here that could cause this?

I got this error while just testing with one user. Would it get even worse if, let's say, 20 users were connected to the website?

If there are too may open connections, how could I make that all requests would be from one connection?

Answer (score 1):

You can, after do whatever you need to do, do this:

```php
$entityManager->getConnection()->close();
```

Or, if you have a class that handles that, you can actually put that code into the __destruct method, then when the garbage collector runs, it will also close the connection, like this:

```php
public function __destruct()
{
   $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   $entityManager->getConnection()->close();
}
```

Comment: But let's take the index() method for example. It does not even have $entityManager. It just uses repositories. How do I close these connections?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems Entity Manager is a Singleton that lives in the request cycle. So, all you need to do is access that entityManager, from wherever you want, using this line: `$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();`
You can do this in your destruct method. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Repositories are just an abstraction. Connection to database is still made through doctrine, but rather somewhere deeper in the abstraction. You could still try the @JoseHenriqueFelipetto 's suggestion

Comment: Can repositories have this destruct method? Would that make sense?

Comment: I wouldnt do this on the Repository Level, since you cant be sure that the connection is not going to be closed before you end the request cycle. You'll have to find somewhere else, maybe at the Connection Class or another, i dont have the exact answer to this, but when i had a similar problem, i needed to implement __destruct methods and close the connection on the Connection class itself.

Comment: But in a conceptual level, all classes can have __destruct methods

Comment: Can I somehow make that all requests would be done by one connection?

Comment: You actually just needs to open the connection once, so you should check if you're not opening new connections. But no, you cannot do that, each request is going to open a new connection on the database